# How to create UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet with horizontal slider as Apple does? (image)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I want to implement social sharing in my app - via `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`.

And want to add icons of Facebook, Twitter, Google+ etc in one line with horizontal swiping - the same way as Apple do, e.g. in sharing for `Notes` app.

I know how to add Cancel button yet )

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"Share" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alert addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But don't know how to add horizontal view with icons.

Could you please help me out?

[image]

Comment: That's a `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't know about such a controller. Could you please add your comment as an answer and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `rmaddy` stated it was an `UIActivityViewController`

My example of using it:

```
// creating an anchor point for UIActivityViewController than will be used on iPad
CGRect pointRect = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"cellRect"] CGRectValue];
CGRect sourceRect = CGRectMake(pointRect.origin.x, pointRect.origin.y + pointRect.size.height, 5, 5);
UIView *sourceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sourceRect];
[self.view addSubview:sourceView];

// prepare object to share
NSString *textToShare = @"Text to share";
NSURL *webSite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com"];
NSArray *itemToShare = @[textToShare, webSite];

// initializing custom UIActivity for "Reddit"
RedditActivity *reddit = [[RedditActivity alloc] init];

// initializing popover UIActivityViewController
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
        initWithActivityItems:itemToShare
        applicationActivities:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:reddit, nil]];

// add anchor point for iPad
if ( [controller respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)] ) {
    controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sourceView;
}

// excluded system UIActivity items
controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
     UIActivityTypePrint,
     UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
     UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
     UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
     UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
     UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
     UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
     UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
     UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks];

// show popover UIActivityViewController
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```